# Deleting a directory and multiple files that begin with the same name

Tags: ant

In my folder I have a directory and three file of similar names

i.e

```
test <-A directory
test.txt
test.something
test.blah
README.txt
```

I am trying to create an ant script to remove all directories and files that begin with `test`

I should only be left with `README.txt`

I am trying to use the delete task but I have been unsuccessful

```
<property name="name" value="test"/> 
<delete dir="${name}"/>
<delete>
          <fileset dir="${name}" includes="${name}*"/>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task tries to delete all the files beginning by "test" that are under the test directory. You should delete all the files beginning by "test" that are under the current directory:

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="." includes="${name}*"/>
</delete>
```